# Django admin widget override for all of abstract model

Tags: django

I have an abstract model that contains a field type that I would like to override the widget for in the admin view.

Now you can't register abstract models in the admin view so I have had to override the widget for each of the models that inherit from the abstract model. This feels clunky - is there a neater way to do this?

**models.py**

```py
class MyAbstractModel(Model):
    field_with_widget_i_want_to_override = MyFieldType()    

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class ModelA(MyAbstractModel):
    extra_field = AnotherFieldType()

class ModelB(MyAbstractModel):
    different_extra_field = ADifferentFieldType()
```

**admin.py**

```
class ModelAAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    formfield_overrides = {
        MyFieldType: {'widget': MyWidget},
    }

class ModelBAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    formfield_overrides = {
        MyFieldType: {'widget': MyWidget},
    }

admin.site.register(ModelA, ModelAAdmin)
admin.site.register(ModelB, ModelBAdmin)
```

Now my actual project is a bit more complicated so I don't want to combine ModelAdmins when registering the models, There are also many more Models that inherit from the abstract base model so I feel like I'm repeating myself alot.

Alternatively is there a way to globally overide the widget used in the admin for a field type (for all models)?

Answer (score 0):

Abstract models can't be registered as ModelAdmin as they are abstract and django can't treat them as data models so most of admin functionalities can't be applied on these classes- so you need to override it with an empty class at least like at documentation here 
[Abstract classes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes) 
There's no way to assign data to abstract models